# What is the behaviour of unique_ptr in this situatuion?

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

I am using a library that provides functions related to randomness (https://github.com/effolkronium/random#is-equal) and I applied one of them that will randomly choose between the 2 objects.

```
    Class object1;
    Class object2;
    std::unique_ptr<Class> p1 = std::make_unique<Class>(Random::get({object1, object2}));
    std::unique_ptr<Class> p2 = std::make_unique<Class>(Random::get({object1, object2}));
```

Because I am using unique_ptr is it certain that these two pointers will always point to a different object?

Comment: What object do you mean, Class object or two objectN? Also post a [mcve].

Comment: It is certain that `p1 != p2`, and also that `&*p1 != &*p2`. But we can tell nothing about `*p1` and `*p2`.

Comment: `Random::get({object1, object2})` [My understanding of the library](https://github.com/effolkronium/random/blob/master/include/effolkronium/random.hpp#L430) is that this will apparently create an array of elements or something, and those elements will be copied from `object1` and `object2`. It will also return a copy of those elements. No pointers are involved at any point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no matter what object is chosen (1 or 2) make_unique will call the copy constructor p1 will not point to object1 or object2 it will create a new object of type 'Class' and will point to that.

-> p1 and p2 will always point to different objects (of type 'Class')
after your lines, you have 4 different objects